# Age cues for humans

Tags: self, aging

We can quickly estimate the age of a person just by the look on the face. Even a computer can do that ([random link](https://howolddoyoulook.com/)). How does this work? Proportions? Creases? Spots? (Note that any theory should include "surrounding" data, since I reproducibly observe the funny fact that when I look in the mirror, I estimate myself much younger that if looking on a photo.)